# Creating link with CGridView

Tags: php, yii

I'm a beginner in the Yii Framework and I want to use a field `idAccounts.name` link in CGridView

```
$post=  Sheduale::model()->search();  
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'users-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$post,
    'columns'=>array(
        'idAccounts.TypeId',
        'idAccounts.name',
                'start',
                'end',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'users-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$post,
'columns'=>array(
    'idAccounts.TypeId',
     array(
            "header"=>"The column header",
             "value"=>function($data, $row){
                   echo "<a></a>" //you can set everything you want here
                //$data refers to each data row in the grid. you can use $data->attribute_name for access attributes of your model
              }
           )
            'start',
            'end',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
));
```

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a [CLinkColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkColumn). You could set its `label` property to whatever text you want to show in the link and use its [`urlExpression`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkColumn#urlExpression-detail) property to generate the URL for each link. The `urlExpression` must be a string that contains PHP (which will be evaluated to figure out what should be used for the link URL). For example:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'users-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $post,
    'columns' => array(
        'idAccounts.TypeId',
        array(
            'class' => 'CLinkColumn',
            'label' => 'View details'
            'labelExpression' => '$data->idAccounts->name',
            'urlExpression' => '\Yii::app()->createUrl('
                . '"controller/action", '
                . 'array("id" => $data->idAccounts->id)'
            . ')',
            'header' => 'Some Column Header',
        ),
        'start',
        'end',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

You would need to replace `controller/action` (in my sample `urlExpression` string) with the actual Yii route that you want the link to go to, and similarly with the sample route parameter used in this example.